# Is the second "to" grammatical in "I plan to help build and then to start"?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, parallelism, particles

I wrote this sentence:

> I plan to help build a strategic vision for Arabic digital content and then **to** start implementing that vision. I want to produce value-added information in a specific context bla bla bla.

Is the *to* grammatically correct in that position?

Comment: Yes, it re-emphasizes that the infinitive _to start_ is on a par with _to help_ and not with _build_. I.e, by using the _to_, you are saying that _you plan to start implementing `bla³`, rather than _you plan to help start implementing `bla³`_.

Comment: Also, it strengthens the parallel structure of the sentence: "...plan to help ... then to start ...".  If you left out the second "to", it would still be grammatical, but less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [*parallelism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).

> The application of parallelism improves writing style and readability,
>   and is thought to make sentences easier to process.

You are asking if the second *to* is correct. Yes, that is correct. If the second *to* is removed, the sentence will also be correct, but defeats the practice of parallelism or balance in a sentence. You might want to read the short article in Wikipedia to understand more the concept of parallelism.

Just want to share... If you are not very keen with the sentence, you would not even notice it. I know a lot of people who do not practice parallelism because I read emails everyday. However, I recommend that you put parallelism into use always.

Comment: But what if you ***meant*** to say; "I plan to help build...and then I plan to help start..."?

Comment: That sentence is different, of course, because you are planning to help build and planning to help start. It's all plans there. If you meant it that way, then you really should include "plan to" at the second part of the sentence.